# Not able to enable push notifications

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

[image: Not able to enable push notifications]
I'm trying to enable push notifications but not able to enable it.
When I'm debugging, I'm getting the Device token, but when I publish, it's not working.

Comment: Looks like that App ID: example.com is not available. Try changing this id.

Comment: Did enpoint created on launching applicaiton?

Comment: Are u using push notification enabled profile ??

Comment: Y it won't available It's my app id ,
I've app in app store with that it, @Phyber

Comment: enpoint,? @IkramTurgunbaev

Comment: I'm trying to use this way through xamarin.studio @ArpitJain

Comment: Still, I'm not able to enable push notifications but I'm getting the device token to my db,what i did is uploaded with distribution certificate, It's giving me some happiness but when I'm testing the notifications in test flight,I'm not getting the notifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without enabling it, notifications working good for me.

We need two certificates for sending notifications,
One for development and one for production
In my case I'm using pushsharp solution to send notification
this is for development

```
var config = new ApnsConfiguration(ApnsConfiguration.ApnsServerEnvironment.Sandbox, "development.p12", "password");
        var broker = new ApnsServiceBroker(config);
```

this is for Production

```
var config = new ApnsConfiguration(ApnsConfiguration.ApnsServerEnvironment.Production, "production.p12", "password");
        var broker = new ApnsServiceBroker(config);
```

It will work without enabling the notifications also,